# How can I write a LINQ query towards a table in the Local Storage Account?

Tags: c#, linq, azure-functions, azure-table-storage, azure-tablequery

Desired flow:

1. HTTP Request to insert data into a table in azure storage. Currently using Postman and localhost. Note: This is running sucessfully and it is step 2 I'm struggeling with. <-- Azure Function
2. When data rows is stored in a table here (tablename = Test) as datatype String, I want to query the data by using a console application. <-- Console Application (se code below)

[image]

Please also look at my comment in the code for my two questions.

Q1) What should storageConnectionString be when I'm only running this locally in the emulator in order to connect to my local table?

Q2) How can I now query all the content in the table or for example row 15 using LINQ and store it in an variable, and print it to console window?

```
using System;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Microsoft.Azure.Cosmos.Table;

namespace demo
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Table storage sample");

            
            var storageConnectionString = "??"; // What should storageConnectionString be when I'm only running this locally in the emulator?
            var tableName = "Test";

            CloudStorageAccount storageAccount;
            storageAccount = CloudStorageAccount.Parse(storageConnectionString);

            CloudTableClient tableClient = storageAccount.CreateCloudTableClient(new TableClientConfiguration());
            CloudTable table = tableClient.GetTableReference(tableName);
        }
    }

    //How can I now query all the content in the table or for example row 15 using LINQ and store it in an variable, and print it to console window?



}
```

POCO

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Microsoft.Azure.Cosmos.Table;

namespace LokalTesting.TableEntities
{
    public class Test: TableEntity
    {

        public Test()
        {

        }
        public Test(string NameId)
        {
            PartitionKey = NameId;
            RowKey = NameId;

        }
        public string NameId { get; set; }
        public string Status { get; set; }
        public string RoutingId { get; set; }
```

Desired output:

```
-All rows where NameId = Jon
```

Comment: Please edit your question and include 1) the code for any POCO model that you're using to emulate storage table entities and 2) sample data that you wish to retrieve via query.

Comment: Hi I have now updated both with POCO and desired output data.

Answer (score 0):

Q1 - Try `"UseDevelopmentStorage=true"`

Q2 -

```
var rows = new List<Test>();
var query = new TableQuery<Test>().Where(TableQuery.GenerateFilterCondition("<propertyName>", QueryComparisons.Equal, propertyValue));

TableContinuationToken continuationToken = null;

do
{
    var queryResult = await table.ExecuteQuerySegmentedAsync(query, continuationToken);
    rows.AddRange(queryResult);
    continuationToken = queryResult.ContinuationToken;
} while (continuationToken != null);
```

Here you can generate the query: `var query = new TableQuery<Test>().Where(TableQuery.GenerateFilterCondition("NameId", QueryComparisons.Equal, "Jon"));`

Comment: With `Microsoft.Azure.Cosmos.Table`, I don't think it is possible to use connection string. Can you please confirm that?

Comment: @GauravMantri I have just run some code locally using `UseDevelopmentStorage=true` and it connected to a local table. Using `Microsoft.Azure.Cosmos.Table`.